# Entity Framework Core: how to execute a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I want to call a function so that it will execute the procedure to see if the username is within the database. I need some help as I have no idea how to do this. I tried so many ways and I am just not getting it right. Thank you.

My procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_login
    @username NVARCHAR(100)
AS
    DECLARE @Isvalid BIT
BEGIN
    SET @Isvalid = (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                    FROM Users 
                    WHERE Username = @username)
    SELECT @Isvalid
END
```

My `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    var configuration = builder.Build();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:UserProfile"]);
}
```

One of the ways I have tried so far in.

My controller:

```
public int LoginCheck(Users ad)
{
    if (ad.Username == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    var clientIdParameter = new SqlParameter("user", ad.Username);

    var result = db.Users.FromSql($"exec sp_login @username", clientIdParameter).ToList();
    int res = Convert.ToInt32(result);

    return res;
}
```

Basically, if the entered user name doesn't match, it will return 0 and redirect to an error page. If it is matched, it will return 1 and will allow the user to proceed.

I tried a lot of ways like shown above. I know how to do the normal `SqlCommand` way. Not sure how to do the Entity Framework way.

Comment: **Side note**: if this is for SQL Server - you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also - which version of EF / EF Core are you using this for? Support for stored procedures has been spotty in EF Core, but getting better with each new version.

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can easily map stored procedures for you